# Can you enable an R function to see the values of its own formals on evaluation?

Tags: r, dynamic, arguments, scoping, lexical-scope

In the R, language, suppose I have a function ff(jj, kk, mm). I would like the calling function (or calling human being in an interactive session) to be able to make mm depend in arbitrary ways on jj and kk at the time of the call.

For concreteness, suppose:

```
ff <- function(jj, kk, mm){
  xx <- jj + kk  
  out<- xx/mm   
  out
}
```

Then at run time, I want to set `mm <- jj*kk`. i.e.:

```
ff(2, 3, (jj*kk))
```

this yields:

```
Error in ff(2, 3, (jj * kk)) : object 'jj' not found
```

This error is not thrown until `mm` is evaluated, i.e. after `jj` and `kk` have already been
evaluated successfully. So they are then evaluated a second time with different scoping 
rules. I understand that this is R-standard scoping. I am asking, can I write the 
function in such a way that it lets me hand mm a simple number, or a function of the 
other formal arguments, provided those arguments have been or can be evaluated before 
`mm` is required?

Note that I am not asking if I should do this. I will stoutly pretend to be polite to people who 
offer views on this latter question.

Nor am I asking if I can pre-calculate jj and hand ff the predigested number. I know 
this is a plausible answer, but it does not work for reasons I have simplified out of 
the problem.

Comment: Just to illustrate the point as to *why* you shouldn't do this, it leads to: `jj=99; kk=101; ff(2,3,(jj*kk))` ignoring the values of `jj` and `kk` you just set because they are evaluated inside the function when equal to 2 and 3 respectively. This would surprise any R user who hasn't read the documentation of `ff`...

Comment: I,m not sure I follow you. If I have a function f<-function(x){x^2}, and I do x<- 3, f(x), I expect to get 9. But if I do f(2) I expect to get 4.  Wait...  I think I see. You are imagining someone else using this function, who did not just write it, yes? I'm pretty sure this project is a one-off, so the issue does not arise in my case. But I see how it could.

Comment: You might find http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html helpful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it stands, your function `ff()` doesn't work because [supplied arguments are evaluated in the context of the calling environment](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Argument-evaluation), from which vantage point neither `jj` nor `kk` are 'visible'.

To evaluate the statement supplied to `mm` within the context of the function's own evaluation frame, use `eval(substitute())`, like so:

```
ff <- function(jj, kk, mm){
  mm <- eval(substitute(mm))
  xx <- jj + kk  
  out<- xx/mm   
  out
}

ff(2, 3, (jj*kk))
## [1] 0.8333333
```

Comment: Also, the parens around `(jj*kk)` aren't necessary - works just as well without them.

Comment: Thanks Josh! That does the job precisely. This may deserve its own question, but I do have a follow-up. What if you want to refer to the function's own environment, as in: LookHere <- function(X){eval(substitute(X), envir = parent.frame(n=0))};  ff <- function(jj, kk, mm){
  mm <- LookHere(mm)
  xx <- jj + kk  
  out<- xx/mm   
  out
}

ff(2, 3, (jj*kk))  Clearly parent.frame(n=0) is wrong. What is right?

Comment: @andrewH -- Hi. I don't have time to explain it right now, but it sounds like you'll want something like `LookHere <- function(X) eval(do.call(substitute, list(substitute(X), env=parent.frame(n=1))), env=parent.frame(n=1))`